# How to search for a specific word in a long string of text field and count them - sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to count a word if how many times it appears in a string or a sentence from a text field. For example:
Declare @text as nvarchar(max)
SET @text = 'Bounce check this date, bounce again then bounce and then bounce again this date. Check BOUNCED'

So, i wanna count how many "bounce" where there. My goal here is to see how our customers perform with their check issuance, we record them that way like a sentence.

I have tried the following code, but it shows more than what it should. Bounce appears 5 but my code counts 8.

```
DECLARE @text as nvarchar(max)
SET @text = 'Bounce what will you bounce do that changed bounce bounce bounce'

SELECT DISTINCT
ISNULL(((Datalength(@text) - Datalength(REPLACE(CAST(@text as nvarchar(max)), 'BOUNCE',4)))/Datalength('BOUNCE')),0) [BounceRate]
```

I expect the output will be 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECLARE @text AS NVARCHAR(max)

SET @text = 'Bounce what will you bounce do that changed bounce bounce bounce'

SELECT (len(@text) - len(replace(@text, 'bounce', ''))) / len('bounce')

can you try this

Comment: Thank you @Dinesh, this solves my question. I just have to replace len() by datalength().